# How to reverse apache proxy for Qlik?

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, qliksense

We have an apache reverse proxy, that is listening on bi.example.ro and I want to forward a request to an internal IP with bi.intranet.example.ro. How can I do that?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName  bi.example.ro
               
               
        ProxyPass / http://10.0.0.167:80/ retry=0               ## 10.0.0.167 is listening to bi.intranet.example.ro not   bi.example.ro
        ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.0.167:80/
        ProxyPreserveHost On
 
 
 
 
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/bi.example.ro-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/bi.example.ro-access.log common
 
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to these official Qlik articles detailing how to set up Apache reverse proxy with Qlik Sense

[Quick guide to configure Apache as a Reverse Proxy with HTTPS, ADFS SAML and Qlik Sense](https://support.qlik.com/articles/000049958)

Also you have this [Reverse Proxy using Apache](https://community.qlik.com/t5/Qlik-Sense-Deployment-Management/Reverse-Proxy-using-Apache/td-p/1137113)

I would suggest that the Qlik Community is  better place to post questions relating to their products [Community](https://community.qlik.com/)